# Issue with designing loop in R for calculating Euclidean Distance Matrix and Mod Value

Tags: r, loops, matrix, euclidean-distance, modulo

My objective is to calculate the determinant of the Euclidean Distance between each index and store the determinant value in a matrix.

I have data as per the below format where columns B1, B2, ... B10 contain Index values.

```
B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  B9  B10
1.9361  0.7853  0.5712  0.5016  0.5810  2.0227  1.7226  2.0001  1.6323  6.6512
2.3522  0.7290  2.0117  1.7894  0.0713  3.0918  1.9928  1.1333  1.4660  14.4510
4.3108  0.7214  1.5651  1.7867  0.0735  5.8460  2.0292  1.8760  2.3937  8.2364
2.2691  0.5049  2.6493  0.6146  0.7974  2.2468  2.0926  0.0885  3.4009  9.7462
1.8998  2.2141  0.2181  0.3453  0.6772  2.7952  2.2791  0.0375  1.6316  6.8325
0.3257  0.6846  0.4051  0.0512  0.2725  3.3828  4.0382  0.3351  0.6275  12.1081
3.3382  1.1726  0.8915  0.8372  0.0773  3.0122  3.0418  0.1817  0.7314  9.9699
0.2584  0.9524  1.3239  0.8226  0.8196  3.6540  2.7760  2.9318  0.3876  2.2691
1.8043  0.5707  0.1201  0.4234  0.4814  2.6493  2.1548  5.1866  0.8284  5.8460
0.6721  2.8143  0.3053  0.3186  0.7406  2.2141  2.7952  0.3861  3.0918  1.7867

The code that I have tried from my end in R, but I am unable to get the result.

Network <- read.csv("Index.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Converting dataframe into matrix

Network_Matrix <- as.matrix(Network)

# Defining the structure of the matrix

Euclidean_Distance_Matrix <- Mod_Euclidean_Distance_Matrix <- matrix(0, 10, 10)

# Loop

for (i in 1:10) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    if (i != j) {
      Euclidean_Distance_Matrix <- as.matrix(dist(Network_Matrix[i,j], method = "euclidean", diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE))
      Mod_Euclidean_Distance_Matrix[i,j] <- det(Euclidean_Distance_Matrix)
    }
  }
}

Mod_Euclidean_Distance_Matrix
```

Comment: Please post your data using `dput()`.  What is your expected output based on your test data?